# Force linker to find stdc++ in non standard directory

Tags: linux, gcc

I've read **a lot** of guidance that says the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is searched before anything else, but one of my .so libraries is linking with `libtdc++.so.6` in `/usr/lib64`.

```
ldd mylib.so:
...
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f82abd18000)
...
```

I want `mylib.so` to link with `libstdc++.so.6` in another location, like `/apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6`

So I add `/apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which ***does not*** have `/usr/lib64` in it, but it still doesn't find it there.

**UPDATE:**

If I add:

```
setenv LD_PRELOAD /apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

to my environment, there are no more linker errors. Yay, but that doesn't solve the problem. Users downstream aren't going to want to depend on this library being in the proper place. WHY ISN"T LD_LIBRARY_PATH BEING SEARCHED FIRST!?!